# How do I stay on the current webpage after a post, without refreshing?

Tags: django-views

After the user updates a datepicker in the html I post that back to my Django class based view and it's persisted in the database under the User object but the post() method requires me to return something. Here's the code below:

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = CreativeUserProfile.objects.get(pk = request.user.id) 

        user.available_date = datetime.strptime(request.POST['availableDate'],'%d/%m/%Y')
        user.save()

        return ??
```

What would you return here to keep the user on the same page without a refresh? Or is this not possible unless I'm using Ajax or something like that?

Cheers in advance

Comment: You can post to a new page by adding the attribute `target = "_blank"` to your form, or you can post to a named `iframe` on the same page by giving the `iframe` a `name` attribute, and using the same value in your form's `target` attribute.

Comment: @spender thanks, but in the django view how would I do that?